# Google IMA event when Ad video is completed/finished

Tags: google-ima

I am new to Google DFP video / Google IMA service. I am reading the following link:

- https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/html5/

And I cannot find any event which would tell if the Ad video is finished playing itself.

Is there a such functionality in Google IMA?

ie.

```
adsLoader.addEventListener(
    google.ima.AdsManagerLoadedEvent.Type[SOME EVENT TYPE HERE],
    [CALLBACK FUNCTION],
false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is the one you are looking for

```
adsManager.addEventListener(
      google.ima.AdEvent.Type.COMPLETE,
      onAdEvent);
```

Comment: That's the one. Thank you!